# Why is this java code executing multiple return statements

Tags: java, android

I have a function that during execution while in the debuger runs both the return statment inside the if and then the return statment at the end of the function.

I'm confused I thought the return statment returned the value and stopped the flow of execution in the method?

I've got it to work, but would like to understand why it is doing this.

As an example in the below. The json will fail on the answer adn the createapprove block. It gets to create fail and ret becomes true (As the json parsed).  The return retval runs and then the code jumps down to the final return retval and executes that as the return for the function.

I'm walking through the code in ecipse in debug mode with the program running on the android emulator.

```
public static ComModelFromServer createModelFromJSON(String json) throws JSONInvalidException {     
     boolean ret = false;
     ComModelFromServer retval = null;

     //Answer Block
     Answer a = new AnswerAsset();
     ret = a.tryToParseFromJSON(json);
     if(ret == true) {
        retval = a;
        return retval;
    }

    Create cr = new CreateApprove();
    ret = cr.tryToParseFromJSON(json);
    if(ret == true) {
        retval = cr;
        return retval;
    }

    cr = new CreateFail();
    ret = cr.tryToParseFromJSON(json);
    if(ret == true) {
        retval = cr;
        return retval;
    }

    if(ret == false) { 
        throw new JSONInvalidException("couldn't create model from JSON");
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I will add each of the tryToParseFromJSon can possibly throw a JSONInvalidException if they hit an error.

Comment: Why on earth do you assign retval and then return it? Why not just eg. return cr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably no problem with this. The compiler probably compiled the `return retval` inside the `if` statements into a jump that jumps to the `return` at the end of the function, which *already* has a `return retval` statement. The debugger showing the odd flow control *doesn't* mean that there is anything wrong.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. There must be something wrong, the eclipse debugger or the android plugin, one of these is not working as expected. But agree, the returned value is the first one, in the line of the second.