# What is right when debugging mode in android eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

It is my source first. :

```
try {
    ((asyncTaskMasterFormList) asyncTask).execute());
    return "a";
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

and I got break point in 'return "a";' and 'return null'.
 but when I do this under debugging mode, It is stopped by return "a"; (It is right.) but also stopped by 'return null;'. and everything is fine.

Is it just android feature?? It is not only try-catch but other return statement.

I don't understand why debugging is stopped by return null; even if It is already return "a";

Comment: `execute` -> `execute()`...typo?

Comment: Is this try/catch inside any kind of loop?

Comment: @IshitaSinha nope, there is no loop, and As mentioned, programming is working well. if debugging point is stopped by 'return "a"', (i think) return null is skipped... but also stop by (even don't do anything..)

Comment: Try/catch should be place inside doInBackground and onPostExecute of asyncTaskMasterFormList

Comment: If there are two breaks in return, that means your code was executed 2 times

Comment: @anhtuannd oh? Thats right. but this point is not a 'execute()' It is just one of examples. I just want to know why break point is stopped by both return "a" and return null.

Comment: @Adrian I have seen this in methods with multiple return values. I don't know the reason for this though.

Comment: @KNeerajLal it can be helpful even if I don't understand yet... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903756/why-is-this-java-code-executing-multiple-return-statements

Comment: breakpoints always hits all returns statements but returns only first one where it hits. In your case, It only hits returns statements in `catch` but it not debug or run the code in catch. To get it, please add some code before return statement in catch part and debug it, Breakpoints only hits return statement not the code.

Comment: @userJP Oh!? sure??? Thanks! Thant's what i want answer. and where can I find the document which have that kind of contents??

Comment: As per my knowledge and experience, I shared this information. I don't have any proof or documentation link.

Comment: @user392117 you should post it as answer. Also add last comment as a footnote. :)